# Why can't backend python compiler return the result?

Tags: python

I am developing a web application, where users can write online code and I'll compile and run the output. I have created a python file where the code gets executed and the output is returned via API response. This is my code snippet

```py
    try:
        filename = request.json['apiPath']

        cmd = 'python' + ' "' + filename + '"'
        result = check_output(cmd, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True).decode('utf-8')

        return jsonify({'terminal': result, 'success': True})

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'terminal': str(e), 'success': False, 'line': False})
```

I am creating a new python file and running that python file here with output stored in a variable and returned using response.

The problem I am facing is that when there is an input in the code, the python compiler stops and waits for the input which should be done on the backend. How will I make this automated?

Comment: When there is an `input` statement in the code, the code is *supposed* to wait for user input to continue. So what do you want it to do exactly? To input a default dummy value? To just skip the input and keep running?

Comment: I want to return response to user so that  user inputs some value and then pass that value back to this code and code should resume from there

Comment: simply the way online code edtiors work like repl or others

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to handle the `input` statement in the server side, you may use the following architecture.

1. when user click `execute` or whatever the submit button is, send them to the server
2. in the server, execute the script one line by one line

   if a `print` statement is hit, store up the result

   if a `input` statement is hit, store the execution process and send the temporary result with the prompt asking for input, then wait for the next request from client
3. when a request for the input is received, continue the execution with the input provided.
4. repeat until the end.

However, to better protect your server and speed up the execution, I suggest you to take a look at Web Assembly, which you can simply put a whole Python script and execute them in the browser.

Comment: I could do exactly what you said but what if there are for loops, if else or some complex logic or a function is called somewhere, how would I do that then?

Comment: As same as the above

Comment: well I know how it should work I need the code.. I am experienced enough to figure out the prototype.. I need the code